# Missing frames when webcam recording with Red5

Tags: actionscript-3, red5, live-streaming

I am trying to save live stream with [this example](http://flashvisions.com/red5/record-live-stream-with-red5-media-server/). I am working on localhost for testing and Red5 version is 1.0.

`streamPublishStart` method receives stream, saves it as flv with `saveAs` method. But my recorded flv files are only 1 frame (not second, checked with GOM Player). But if i attach a listener to stream and check received packages, i can see they are keep coming.

This is how i tested it;

```
public void streamPublishStart(IBroadcastStream stream) {
    try {
        stream.addStreamListener(new IStreamListener() {
            @Override
            public void packetReceived(IBroadcastStream streamObj, IStreamPacket packet) {  
                System.out.println(packet.getTimestamp() + " - " + packet.getDataType());
            }
        });

        stream.saveAs(stream.getPublishedName(), false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This code printed timestamps until i stopped recording. I tried to save these bytes from received packages and merge them with file `saveAs` method created, nothing happened.

What can be the problem? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgrade to [Red5 0.8.0 Final](https://code.google.com/p/red5/), Java 6 and used [SimpleRecorder example](http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/flash/trunk/samples/), it worked.

I couldn't find the source of oflaDemo but you can convert classes to .java files with [JD java decompiler](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui)

oflaDemo classes are in the `webapps/oflaDemo/WEB-INF/classes` directory after you install it from installer.

It is not an actual answer but this will stay as right answer until a better one appears.